# Exception from Jenkins during initialization

Tags: jenkins, exception

I am running a Jenkins server based on https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins LTS. While running version 2.332.1, I have noticed the following exceptions during initialization, which I have not seen before.

Any help regarding how to solve this is highly appreciated.

```
Attaching to jenkins-server_jenkins_1
jenkins_1  | Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
jenkins_1  | webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:54.755+0000 [id=1]    INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @407ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:54.828+0000 [id=1]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:54.855+0000 [id=1]    WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:54.907+0000 [id=1]    INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.43.v20210629; built: 2021-06-30T11:07:22.254Z; git: 526006ecfa3af7f1a27ef3a288e2bef7ea9dd7e8; jvm 11.0.14.1+1
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:55.131+0000 [id=1]    INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:55.163+0000 [id=1]    INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:55.163+0000 [id=1]    INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:55.164+0000 [id=1]    INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#startScavenging: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:55.548+0000 [id=1]    INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /var/jenkins_home found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:55.707+0000 [id=1]    INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@74cf8b28{Jenkins v2.332.2,/,file:///var/jenkins_home/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/jenkins_home/war}
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:55.735+0000 [id=1]    INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@6c6cb480{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:55.735+0000 [id=1]    INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started @1389ms
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:55.744+0000 [id=24]   INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:55.975+0000 [id=30]   INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:56.145+0000 [id=29]   INFO    hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy#createPluginWrapper: Plugin discard-old-build.jpi is disabled
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:56.231+0000 [id=29]   INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:58.245+0000 [id=34]   WARNING hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz#scout: Failed to scout org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.endpoints.ModelConverterAction
jenkins_1  | java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.fge.jsonschema.tree.JsonTree
jenkins_1  |    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1402)
jenkins_1  |    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1357)
jenkins_1  |    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1112)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
jenkins_1  | Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/fge/jsonschema/tree/JsonTree
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz.scout(ExtensionFinder.java:730)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:352)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:384)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:320)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ExtensionList.getComponents(ExtensionList.java:184)
jenkins_1  |    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$6.onInitMilestoneAttained(Jenkins.java:1188)
jenkins_1  |    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1.onAttained(InitReactorRunner.java:88)
jenkins_1  |    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.lambda$onAttained$3(ReactorListener.java:108)
jenkins_1  |    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.run(ReactorListener.java:115)
jenkins_1  |    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.onAttained(ReactorListener.java:108)
jenkins_1  |    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$1.run(Reactor.java:183)
jenkins_1  |    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:121)
jenkins_1  |    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:24:59.388+0000 [id=34]   WARNING h.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$SezpozModule#configure: Failed to load org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.endpoints.ModelConverterAction
jenkins_1  | java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.fge.jsonschema.tree.JsonTree
jenkins_1  |    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1402)
jenkins_1  |    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1357)
jenkins_1  |    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1112)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
jenkins_1  | Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/fge/jsonschema/tree/JsonTree
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2357)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$SezpozModule.resolve(ExtensionFinder.java:501)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$SezpozModule.resolve(ExtensionFinder.java:487)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$SezpozModule.configure(ExtensionFinder.java:531)
jenkins_1  |    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:64)
jenkins_1  |    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:409)
jenkins_1  |    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:108)
jenkins_1  |    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:160)
jenkins_1  |    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
jenkins_1  |    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
jenkins_1  |    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder.<init>(ExtensionFinder.java:281)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
jenkins_1  |    at net.java.sezpoz.IndexItem.instance(IndexItem.java:181)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz._find(ExtensionFinder.java:706)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz.find(ExtensionFinder.java:692)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:358)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:384)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:320)
jenkins_1  |    at hudson.ExtensionList.getComponents(ExtensionList.java:184)
jenkins_1  |    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$6.onInitMilestoneAttained(Jenkins.java:1188)
jenkins_1  |    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1.onAttained(InitReactorRunner.java:88)
jenkins_1  |    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.lambda$onAttained$3(ReactorListener.java:108)
jenkins_1  |    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.run(ReactorListener.java:115)
jenkins_1  |    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.onAttained(ReactorListener.java:108)
jenkins_1  |    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$1.run(Reactor.java:183)
jenkins_1  |    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:121)
jenkins_1  |    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
jenkins_1  |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:25:00.320+0000 [id=34]   INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Prepared all plugins
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:25:00.345+0000 [id=37]   INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started all plugins
jenkins_1  | 2022-05-03 12:25:00.369+0000 [id=34]   INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Augmented all extensions
```

How do I find out what causes this and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. The "Pipeline: Nodes and Processes" plugin was not updated because Jenkins said it was incompatible. After updating it the exception is gone, and it seems like the whole system is still running

Comment: Hi, Tue. I have the same error in Jenkins 2.346.3. So, I check out your proposal and found I have already the last version of Pipeline: Nodes and Processes 199.v02b_9244f8064 . Your approach not helps me (